# A simple if statement in javascript needing explaination

Tags: javascript

I am learning `javascript` and have I am trying to understand what is going on with an `if` statement such as this (taken from a `javascript` tutorial):

```
var count = 2;

if (count & 2) {
    document.write(count); 
}
```

As it stands **count** will be written. However if I set **count** to **4** (ie so that **count % 2** is still **0**) why is **count** not written?

Comment: 4 & 2 == 0 which is falsey ...

Comment: Why does `count % 2` matter? You aren't testing that.

Comment: Don't confuse 4&2 with 4%2

Comment: & means bitwise and. % means modulo.

Comment: Very stupid of me. Thanks

Comment: You should look for modulus operator but not Bitwise And operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are falling into bitwise operations :

`if` will be invoked when a `truthy` value is achieved.

`2&2` is : 
 `10 & 10` which is `10` which is `2` which is `truthy` so the if succeedes

But `4&2` is `100 & 010` which is  `0` which is `falsy`.

OK ?

Comment: I got it - thanks. I was being stupid

Comment: @RichardGriffiths No you did not. don't underestimate yourself.

Comment: What I meant was I know understand. I got it from someone else ... true. Thanks for your help - now understand bitwise too.

Answer (score 3):

`&` means `bitwise and`

```
count = 2
count & 2 => 10 & 10 = 10 (true)

count = 4
count & 2 => 100 & 010 = 0 (false)
```

Comment: From failing to put % and using & I have made a silly mistake but now learned about the binary comparator. Very helpful thanks.